# Microsoft Access - Creating a single search function for multiple queries

Tags: sql, database, forms, ms-access

I have a form where I would like to include a search function. Optimally this would include a combo box where the user can select their Search Field, i.e. Name, SSN, etc. and a text box to retrieve input.

There will be two tables I'd like the information to pulled from. So I assume I'll need two subforms, each with a query for that table. Is there a way to tie in the combo and text boxes to both of these queries at once?

My ultimate goal is to allow users to search for a record (an address), which may be in one of two tables, then select that record and have it appended to a third table which will be a separate subform.

This is basically my solution to relating addresses with people to reduce the amount of typing necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't write a custom search function, Access already has that feature built in for worksheets.  You can give them two worksheets or union the rows from the two tables into a single worksheet (better, because they only search once,) and insert their selection when they double-click on the row they want to select.

Comment: What you want to do is possible without separate sub forms, but it will require dynamically populating the combo box using VBA.